# I set UITextView keyboardType attributes to. PhonePad, appeared the following questions

Tags: ios, keyboard

[image]

I set UITextView keyboardType attributes to. PhonePad, appeared the following questions.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: If your app working correctly despite the message?

Comment: My application can work normally，log shows the warning information.